# Remove everything but one file tcsh

Tags: terminal, tcsh

I basically want to do the following bash command but in tcsh:

```
rm !(file1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does that really work in bash? I just get "`-bash: !: event not found`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ls -1` (that's the number one, not the lowercase letter L) to list one file per line, and then use `grep -vx <pattern>` to exclude (`-v`) lines that exactly (`-x`) match `<pattern>`, and then `xargs` it to your command, `rm`. For example,

```
ls -1 | grep -vx file1 | xargs rm
```

In case your version of `grep` doesn't support the `-x` option, you can use anchors:

```
ls -1 | grep -vx '^file1$' | xargs rm
```

---

To use this with commands other than `rm` that may not take an arbitrary number of arguments, remember to add the `-n 1` option to `xargs` so that arguments are handled one by one:

```
ls -1 | grep -vx '^file1$' | xargs -n 1 rm
```

---

I believe you can also achieve this using `find`'s `-name` option to specify a parameter by negation, *i.e.* the `find` utility itself may support expressions like `!(file1)`, though you'll still have to pipe the results to `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

tcsh has a special `^` syntax for glob patterns (not supported in csh, sh, or bash). Prefixing a glob pattern with `^` negates it, causing to match all file names that *don't* match the pattern.

Quoting the tcsh manual:

> An entire glob-pattern can also be negated with `^':
>
> ```
>        > echo *
>        bang crash crunch ouch
>        > echo ^cr*
>        bang ouch
> ```

A single file name is not a glob pattern, and so the `^` prefix doesn't apply to it, but it can be turned into one by, for example, surrounding the first character with square brackets.

So this:

```
rm ^[f]ile1
```

*should* remove all files in the current directory other than `file1`.

I strongly recommend testing this before using it, either by using an `echo` command first:

```
echo ^[f]ile1
```

or by using <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> to expand the pattern to a list of files before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

UPDATE: I've since learned that bash supports similar functionality but with a different syntax. In bash, `!(PATTERN)` matches anything *not* matched by the pattern. This is not recognized unless the `extglob` shell option is enabled. Unlike tcsh's `^` syntax, the pattern can be a single file name. This isn't relevant to what you're asking, but it could be useful if you ever decide to switch to bash.

zsh probably has something similar.